# Is the subspace of circles of the 2-sphere closed?

Tags: general-topology

i'm trying to prove or disprove the following conjecture. Suppose $d$ is a metric on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ such that $d\leq 1$. We can give $K(\mathbb{S}^2)$ (the set of compact sets of the sphere) the Hausdorff metric $d_H$. Now consider the set $X=\{ C \subseteq \mathbb{S}^2 : C \text{ is a maximal circle }\}$. We have that $X \subseteq K(\mathbb{S}^2)$. The question i'm trying to answer is: The set $X$ is closed in $K(\mathbb{S}^2)$?

I'm guessing that this is indeed true. Some things that may be helpfull is Kechris's Classical Descriptive Set Theory book, especially the section called "The hyperspace of compact sets".

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is $d_H$ defined?

Comment: What do you mean by a "maximal circle"? Do you mean a **[great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle)**?

Comment: @Gibbs: This is quite standard, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance.